# Fill textview text with csv file of persian words

Tags: android, textview, persian, farsi

I have a csv file of persian words. I want to read from it and show those words on android textview. Reading from file is ok but the problem is that it always shows **diamonds with question mark** on it for textview text. (When I put persian words inside string.xml file and bind them to textview, it works perfectly but I don't know what is the problem with reading them from some external files)

My android version is 4.1

Comment: I think the problem may be with the character encoding. csv does not include encoding information

Comment: Look here, [its a similar csv issue with persian characters](http://www.dailyfreecode.com/forum/persian-characters-not-shown-correctly-20576.aspx)

Comment: `Reading from file is ok`. No you do the reading wrong. You are not accounting for the character encoding.

Comment: @NadeemIqbal: You are right, the problem was with encoding. I set an encoding for csv file but it dosen't change anything. So I transfer my data into an text file with utf8 encoding. Is there a way to set an encoding for csv file?

Comment: @greenapps: Thanks, please take a look at previous comment